# Nativescript failing after upgrade

Tags: nativescript

Having been away from development for a while due to lockdown, I have run in to some issues updating a project. I have removed platforms, node_modules and package-lock.json, but cannot update the project.

I get the following error after running ns update: -

npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, your authentication token seems to be invalid.
npm ERR! To correct this please trying logging in again with:
npm ERR!     npm login

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/nick/.npm/_logs/2021-01-25T15_48_02_897Z-debug.log
Could not update the project! Reason is: Command npm failed with exit code 1

I have run npm logout and nom login and the login works. I have updated fevents with npm i fsevents, but that still trows an error. Nativescript is 7.1.1

Really stuck as what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I advise to not use the ns update. The better way is to setup a new project on the new NS version and after that move the source files in it from your old one.

After that, you'll have to change your dependencies from `tns-core-modules` to `@nativescript/core`, updated plugins one by one, etc. However, it looks like a hard one it is a much more stable way IMHO.